# Verifying if these Cayley tables are from groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

[image]

For the first table I noticed that

$ab = c \implies abb = cb \implies a = cb$ but in the table, $cb = d$, so this can't be a group

For the second table, we have:

$ab = c \implies (aa)b = ac \implies bb = ac \implies e = ac$ but $ac = d$ in the table, so this can't be a group too.

Am I rigth?

Comment: In the first cayley table assuming it is a group, it being of order five (prime order) should be cyclic which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the elements are known to be distinct then you are right in both cases. Else you're first "group" gives you the relation $a=d$ so this could be true and you need to check further, and similarly for the second one.

Also in the first cayley table, notice how the diagonal is just the identity. This tells you that every (nontrivial) element has order 2 and this implies that the "group" is abelian (assuming it is a group), which simplifies matters.

Comment: The diagonal in the first table is NOT just the identity, did you notice that one entry is $c$? (Or maybe I am missing something).